# Custom 404 page React Router displays on all pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to render a custom 404 page. From the docs and most peoples suggestions it seems the best way to accomplish this is:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    ....a bunch of other routes
  <Route path="*" components={NotFound}/>
 </switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The problem is that is renders these things at the bottom of every component. Any insight on why this would be the case...?

Comment: Can we see "other bunch of routes"? Also, you have some typos there, it is better to paste the real code here.

Comment: where in the docs does it say to use `path="*"` for 404? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Switch JSX element.
With the switch only one router will be rendered.

I see that you already use it.
It seems like you have a typo in the closing tag, it should be Switch with a first capital letter and you should pass component prop and not components

Moreover, try to omit the path in the 404 Route element, pass only the component.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is just the  element when it will sense the capital letter it will work and wont render the 'Page not found..' 
and like other people said change components to component:)